# why vs code not recognizing the node version

Tags: solidity, truffle, nodejs, truffle-test, visual-studio-code

when I install a "truffle for vs code" extension in vs code and try to create a new solidity project then nodejs version is not recognized but I have installed nodejs's correct version.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Use nvm it is an easy way to manage your node version

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's hidden, if you open the webview developer console from vscode, you can see that two messages are loaded and if you expand one of them multiple times (it's very nested) you can see that the max version supported is node 17.0.0 and the min ver is 14.0.0,

So if you install any lts node version it should upon restart recognize it,

But for me it worked only using nvm and setting the default alias with this command:

> nvm alias default lts/*

then

> nvm use default

when i did not use the default command it would still not recognize node even if the version was indeed correct.

[image]

Edit: Following the issue pages on GitHub:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/vscode-ext/issues/128

https://github.com/trufflesuite/vscode-ext/issues/115

Comment: you need to add quites arount the lts `nvm alias default "lts/*"` however this is still not working for me